# LinkedIn API - Refresh Access Token after 60 days - PHP

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I need to refresh token after 60 days in linkedin PHP API

Can you tell me how to send API request .I also tried this link

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token..

Please give some idea to refresh the access token of Linkedin API

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: How to fetch the response from link https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken  . It is possible to redirect the response to my page.. Now I simply get the empty screen..

Answer (score 0):

Send the user through the exact same process you created for them to Authenticate the account in the first place.

If the User is logged in to the authenticated LinkedIn account already, then LinkedIn will send the user straight to your callback URL that you have defined, along with a brand new Access Token with a fresh 60 days on it.

Unfortunately, LinkedIn doesn't implement the oAuth grant_type=refresh token defined in the standard.

Comment: I realise this is an old question, this is still ranking high on google for related searches and there seems to be a lot of confusion around the subject

Answer (score 0):

**LinkedIn only handle the automatic code refresh if the user is logged into Linked In with the same browser.**

So, here is how the worklflow looks like:

a) I'm logged into LinkedIn:

1. I have a link

   href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&redirect_uri=my_redirect_uri"
2. Everytime I'm redirected to my_redirect_uri I get a GET parameter"code" which allows me to request a new access token throw

   "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken"

b) I'm not logged in on LinkedIn on this browser:

I need to re-authenticate every time I click on the link...